# How do I avoid "invalid URL" error when creating a new organization in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-organization

I have tried to create a new organization in my Trello account, and get all the time the same error-message "invalid URL".

I see three data-fields, and type various alternatives with and without dots and caps and etc.

The message rules all as errors.

Comment: What URL are you using for the organization?  Does it include an `http://`?